# How to synchronize MongoDB async query in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, q

I have a for-loop statement and an async MongoDB inside loop body. What I want to do is to make a `find` query from my MongoDB database, and push the result into an Array.

Here is the code:

```
function() arrResult() {
  var arr = [];
  for(...) {
    collection.find({ foo: i }, function (err, cursor) {
      arr.push(cursor);   
    }    
  }
  return arr;
}
```

But it's obvious that the return value of the function would be an empty Array.

I want to tackle this problem using `Q` module. Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to tackle this problem using Q module. Is there any solutions?

Yes, promises are a very easy abstraction to deal with this. You can execute the queries in parallel, and collect their results with [`all`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-promiseall).

In particular, with `Q` it would look like this:

```
function arrResult(…) {
    var promises = [];
    for (…)
        promises.push( Q.ninvoke(collection, "find", {foo: i}) );
    return Q.all(promises);
}

arrResult(…).then(function(arr) {
    …
}, function(err) {
    // first error, if any occured
});
```

Comment: Great. Could you please complete it using `Q.defer()`?

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani: Why would I need to? One [never uses `Q.defer`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#wiki-the-deferred-anti-pattern) manually. `Q.ninvoke` and the other [callback-function method](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-promise-for-function-methods) perfectly avoid this.

Comment: Just for educational purposes.

Comment: I think that's pretty well covered in [*Using deferreds* in the Q docs](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/#using-deferreds). You can translate the example with `FS.readFile` directly into one for `collection.find`

Answer (score 1):

You need a sync mechanism that acts like a process gate.
Each returning query has to arrive at the gate, e.g. decrements some counter and deposit its result.
When all arrived at the gate, a final callback does return the collected results.

Comment: Interesting...do you have any examples of this? I'm pretty intrigued

Comment: I hand coded such, but it must exist in the Node.js ecosystem. gimme a moment.

Comment: @mvw: You're looking for [async.js' `parallel` function](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel)… However, notice that OP wants to use Q.

Comment: @Bergi: yes. The q Solution i don't know.